# How to handle blob store url when receive from API

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an API URL (e.g.: localhost:8080/api/blobs/download/{item-id}). The API itself will return the URL of that item in the Blob Store (for example, https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myitem).
Now I have a task that requires user to copy and paste the API URL into the browser, and expect it to view/download the item.

The question is how Java can support user browse the Blob Store URL without the help of the front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your java application to download a file from a given URL?

There is no need for user interactions.

See example below using Java NIO:

> The Java NIO package offers the possibility to transfer bytes between
> 2 Channels without buffering them into the application memory.
>
> To read the file from our URL, we'll create a new ReadableByteChannel
> from the URL stream:

```
ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
```

> The bytes read from the ReadableByteChannel will be transferred to a
> FileChannel corresponding to the file that will be downloaded:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);

FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
```

> We'll use the transferFrom() method from the ReadableByteChannel class
> to download the bytes from the given URL to our FileChannel:

```
fileOutputStream.getChannel()
  .transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

> The transferTo() and transferFrom() methods are more efficient than
> simply reading from a stream using a buffer. Depending on the
> underlying operating system, the data can be transferred directly from
> the filesystem cache to our file without copying any bytes into the
> application memory.
>
> On Linux and UNIX systems, these methods use the zero-copy technique
> that reduces the number of context switches between the kernel mode
> and user mode.

There are other libraries that you can use as well, that might be better than using Java NIO on its own.

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file

Comment: Thank you Susan, I've accepted your answer :). Sorry for the long response.

Comment: No worries @Duy Hope it helps you